# Is it possible to combine IdentityDbContext with my app's DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I have a distinct database using the Identity Library IdentityDbContext class to define the database.

And I have my own MyAppDbContext for all the data in my application.

I do want the Identity Library to retain its own distinct tables. But is there a way to create a combined DbContext that encompasses both sets of tables (models)? By doing so, as I have an AppModel in my app's DbContext, it would make database I/O on the pairs of objects a lot simpler.

This is for Blazor server side on .NET 8.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Usually the question comes from wanting to reference Users from other application tables like CreatedBy/ModifiedBy, You can definite entities for User for instance within your MyAppDbContext so that you can still take advantage of FK references without risking exposing Roles etc. The IdentityDbContext should only be used for auth checks while your app DbContext is used for all application related querying once authenticated & authorized.

Comment: @StevePy If you write that as an answer, happy to accept it. And thank you, I trust your knowledge and you've now saved me several hours of frustrating wasted effort.